# Alter table query in MS Access 2007

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2008, ms-access-2007

I want a MS Access query that can add a column to my current table. Query should include `NOT NULL` constraint, `DEFAULT` value as `''` i.e. 2 single quotes and the data type.

I tried this query in Access 2007 but this is not working:

```sql
ALTER TABLE Demo ADD COLUMN LName TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT ('')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE {TABLENAME} 
ADD {COLUMNNAME} {TYPE} {NULL|NOT NULL} 
CONSTRAINT {CONSTRAINT_NAME} DEFAULT {DEFAULT_VALUE}
```

OR TRY

```
ALTER TABLE TestTable
ADD NewCol VARCHAR(50)
CONSTRAINT DF_TestTable_NewCol DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
GO
```

Comment: Can you tell me how will the code be written if my table name is 'Demo', column name I want to add is 'LName', type 'TEXT(15)', NOT NULL and DEFAULT value as (' ').

Comment: well first of all DEFAULT is not recognized in MS ACCESS!To achieve what you want to do you should use two different queries.First you add the column and second update the table to set the default value of the field

Comment: Ya. Even i thought so. That worked. First add a row. Then alter it to set the default.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ADD ColumnName(50) NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: You need to add **size of text column**.

```
ALTER TABLE Demo ADD COLUMN LName TEXT(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
```

Note: I am adding 15 just as example. You can add whatever is right for ur code.

Comment: Still the same. The error is with DEFAULT. It gets highlighted after I run the code.